# Show category post order ASC

Tags: categories

Below is my category.php page code. I want to order by `ASC`. How can I achieve this?

```
<div class="content">
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
  <h2>    <?php single_cat_title('',true); ?>  </h2>
<ul class="products">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    ?>

    <li> <a href="<?php 
    $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'productURL', true); 

    if ($url) {
        echo "$url";
    }
?>" target="_blank">
      <?php  the_post_thumbnail() ?>
      <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
      <?php endwhile; 
            ?>
      </a></li>

  <?php else : ?>
  <?php endif; ?></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

When you decided to **unaccept** my answer and change your question in the comments to my answer I was already in bed. Please consider @kaiser comment next time when asking a question.

For the purpose of my answer, here is your comment

> i am having problem.. actually i want to show order by alphabet . like
>   A B C....but it not working that way. any idea how
>
> $query->set( 'orderby','title', 'order', 'ASC' ); not work

You cannot pass two arguments to `$query->set`. You need to add each argument separately, so to achieve your goal, this is how your code will look like

```
function wpse_asc_cat_pages( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_asc_cat_pages' );
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You can achieve this by simply using [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

This code goes in to your functions.php. This function checks whether you are on a category page and if this is the main query, and if both exists, it orders the posts ASC

```
function wpse_asc_cat_pages( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_asc_cat_pages' );
```

Comment: i am having problem.. actually i want to show order by alphabet . like A B C....but it not working that way. any idea how

Comment: `$query->set(  'orderby','title', 'order', 'ASC' );`

not work

Comment: @AccoreLTD (1) There is a "help" link below "Add Comment". Please use it to gain the ability to write properly formatted comments. (2) "not work" is a problem description that ... does "not work". It's too vague. _What_ does not work? Expectations vs. Outcome ... as [edit] to your question please. (3) Please be more accurate when asking questions. Else you are wasting the time people invest in trying to help you like Pieter Goosen just did. Thanks for keeping that in mind for this and further questions.